# okHttpClient response gives garbage value

Tags: java, json, android-studio, okhttp

I'm trying to register a user using okHttpClient 4.2.1 library and as a response I'm getting some garbage value

```
Respone is  �������������V*.MNN-.V�JK�)N�Q�r�S���rR�SSR��K2��t�RK���ck�NY�<������
```

I used postman and the response is what I'm expecting. I don't understand why its not working in Android Studio.

```
{"result": {"OTP": 1113401845,"id": 143},"success": true,"message": "User Registered In Successfully"}
```

Here is the code I used

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();
try {
    postdata.put("action", "registrationFirst");
    postdata.put("User_name", "abcd");
    postdata.put("password", "12345");
    postdata.put("email", "aaaa3@a.com");
    postdata.put("street", "qa");
    postdata.put("Gender", "1");
    postdata.put("Religion", "3");
    postdata.put("caste", "Other");
    postdata.put("Country", "UAE");
    postdata.put("mobile", "0123456");
    postdata.put("Locaion", "SHJ");
} catch(JSONException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,postdata.toString());

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(myUrl)
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic aW5mb0Bhbm9vbnouY29tOjEyMTIxMg==")
        .addHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1")
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .addHeader("Postman-Token", "cf631a82-2570-4c20-9c39-be0563240c67,f9cecf3d-2340-4fce-bb6f-c060c9f8894f")
        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .addHeader("Content-Length", "1278")
        .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build();

Response response = null;

try {
    response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

        String result = response.body().string();
        Log.d("Hola","Response is "+result);

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Hola","Failed exception "+e);

}
```

Comment: Probably you have the wrong encoding set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the following line when building a request using `Request.Builder`:

```
addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
```

When you specify your own `Accept-Encoding` value you're implying that you'd like to do your own decompression which is not the case for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Android Studio do not decompress the response and show it to you compressed.
You might want to remove the header "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate" for this to work properly.